# How to set a value to a key in application.conf file in Play Framework (Java) 2.3.x

Tags: java, email, playframework, playframework-2.3

I have Play mailer configured on application.conf file with one email id . how can i change the email dynamically during run time ?  The idea is to configure multiple email IDs on a single play application . eg ; for sales  , the email must be sent from sale@abc.com and for purchase , purchase@abc.com

```
smtp.host=smtp.zoho.com
smtp.port=465
smtp.ssl=true
smtp.user= "info@abc.com"
smtp.password= "something"
```

i can get the string value using `Play.application().configuration().getString("smtp.host");`  ; how do we set it during run time ?

Answer (score 3):

Play Configuration wraps [Typesafe Config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config), which is immutable. So you cannot modify a config after creation. You can only create another config based on this one, overriding some properties.

Comment: Which means I can have multiple configuration files , with different configured email ids ?

Comment: Yes, you can. You can also create many configs programmatically. But I don't know if you can use them in your mailer library. You might want to search for ways of configuring the mailing library in its docs.

Answer (score 0):

The recipients of emails are set in your code, using the addTo method on a play.libs.mailer.Email object :
https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer/blob/2.x/sample/app/controllers/ApplicationJava.java#L18

Not to be confused with the login and password of your SMTP provider. These are sets in application.conf :
https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer/blob/2.x/sample/conf/application.conf#L65

Comment: yes i can send to any user using addTo method , how to configure multiple ,SMTP provider.

Comment: If you just want to change the replyTo field, use the 'setFrom' method. If you really want to use two different SMTP servers, you can try to write your own play.libs.mailer.MailerPlugin (see https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer/blob/2.x/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/mailer/MailerPlugin.scala#L55 ) or pass a custom play.api.Application to the send method of your own play.libs.mailer.MailerPlugin (see https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer/blob/2.x/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/mailer/MailerPlugin.scala#L25 )